# Is there a way to hide the header or site content only when displayed on a page on blogger?

Tags: html, hide, blogger, show-hide, show

I put some HTML code in the header and is shown all throughout the blogger website but I want it to be hidden when someone goes to another page on the website. So the question is, is it possible selectively hide things when they are opened in additional page but still have them shown on the home page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue adding this CSS code:

`filter: brightness(0) invert(1);`